# Spring Boot: Add a User Role ("USER", "ADMIN") into ResponseEntity

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

I have the @RestController. How can I send a User Role (String type for example "ADMIN") to my React web-application? I've implemented two steps for it, but I think it's not a good solution. Thank you.

SPRING BOOT

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
        //...details      
        // Build response with the generated token
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + jwts)
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "Authorization")
                .build();
    }
```

REACT

```
const login = () => {
    /*STEP1 - authenticate*/
    fetch(SERVER_URL + 'login/authentication', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      const jwtToken = res.headers.get('Authorization');
      
      if (jwtToken !== null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("jwt", jwtToken);
        setAuth(true);
        
        /*STEP2 - get role*/
        fetch(SERVER_URL + 'users/'+user.username+'/role', {
          headers: { 'Authorization' : jwtToken }
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(res => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("userRole", res);
        })
        .catch(err2 => console.error(err2));
      }
      else {
        setOpen(true);
      }
    })
    .catch(err1 => console.error(err1))
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in your, login/authentication api when the user is successfully authenticated, then provide user roles in json response, you can also provide token in json instead of header, below is the approach I follow, that might be helpful to you.

```
 {
  "user": {
    "name": "lorem ipsum",
    "role": "admin"
  },
  "token": "jwt token"
}
```

In this way you can avoid two api call and in login you will provide user response with role and token.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I plan to redirect user to userPage or adminPage. Maybe it's not a good way to use authentication from react. Sprig boot provides its own solution using /login and redirect.